# Why does this code keep looping despite no loop?

Tags: c++

As the title says, I'm unable to figure out why this code keep on lopping when the input is not of an integer but a string.

Edit: Seems like you misunderstood my question, let me clarify and pase all the code.

I don't want to quit the program after I finished typing the teacher, because there's a case (case 0) that handle that. What I want to know is why the code keep looping if I enter a string in the part where it's asking for `birtdate` instead of an integer, but work fine if I enter an integer.

In this case, if an interger where to be entered, the program behaves as expected, but when it's a string, the program keep on looping the part where it asks for the `birthdate`. Even afte removing the `if` and `else`, it's still do the same thing, in which it should crash since there's no error handle.

```
  int main()
{
    string tempName;
    int tempYear;
    char input = 't';
    bool exit = 0;
    do
    {
        cout << "Please choose one of the following options:" << endl;
        cout << "0. Quit" << endl;
        cout << "1. Add new Teacher" << endl;
        cout << "2. Add new Assistant" << endl;
        cout << "3. Add new TA-personel" << endl;
        cout << "4. Show all Staff" << endl;
        cout << "You chose: ";
        cin >> input;
        cout << endl;

        switch (input)
        {
        case '0':
            exit = 1;
            break;
        case '1':
            cout << "Please enter the name of the teacher: ";
            cin >> tempName;
            cin.ignore();

            cout << "Please enter the birthdate of the teacher: ";
            cin >> tempYear;
            cin.ignore();
            if (!cin.fail())
            {
                //Nothing
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "The input was not a number!";
                cout << "1. Please enter the birthdate of the teacher: ";
                cin >> tempYear;
            }
            break;
        case '2':
            break;
        case'3':

            break;
        case '4':

            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (exit == 0);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps exit is 0 and it gets stuck. Drop full source somewhere

Comment: No, do not "drop" your "full source" anywhere. Post the MCVE you have been debugging with for the past few hours.

Comment: You describe everything except the most obvious reason -- `exit` is 0 when `while (exit == 0);` is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code (or your full MCVE, anyway, which you neglected to share -.-) will always loop, because you never change the value of the poorly-named variable `exit`.

#### Update

Remember when you checked for `!cin.fail()`? That was the right thing to do, but you didn't unset the fail flag for the next attempt.

```
cin.clear();
```

Comment: possibly there isn't even a variable `exit` and it is checking if `&std::exit` is not a null pointer

Comment: But even if I were to remove the if and else statement, as stated in the post. the program still act the same.

Comment: @thenoob: The if statement checks for `cin.fail()`. But even if you don't check for the fail flag, it will still be set!! So you still need to clear it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not modifying the `exit` variable inside the loop.

So the condition of the `while` loop is always true if `exit` was set to `0` before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the code is incomplete.

1.You need to change the value of the variable name "exit" to a non-zero value  in the switch-case to end the loop which corresponds to the user selecting the exit option.

2. You need to ask for a new choice from the user inside the do-while loop and before the switch statement starts.
3. Change the variable type of your tempyear to string.
   for example:

char choice;

```
do
{
   cin>>choice;

   switch(choice)
   {
       case '0': exit=1;
                 break;
   }

}while(exit==0)
```

This will end the loop when the user enters 0

**UPDATE**

The reason that it goes into infinite loop when you enter a string value in the int variable *tempyear* is that the **bad input** flag of *cin* is set after you enter the string.

To fix it you need to use **cin.clear()** after **cin.ignore()** so that the bad input flag is reset and it takes input again- as pointed out by @Lightness Races in Orbit